# How to convert jQuery code to Pure JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to convert jQuery to Pure JavaScript but it doesn't work.

jQuery:

```
(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".js-all-btn").on("click", this, function()
    {
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        $(".js-all-content").toggleClass("a-block");
    }
);
});
```

To Pure:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function()
{
    document.querySelector(".js-all-btn").on("click", this, function()
    {
        document.querySelector(this).toggleClass("active");
        document.querySelector(".js-all-content").toggleClass("a-block");
    });
});
```

Result:
`document.querySelector(...).on is not a function`

As you can see unfortunately doesn't work. So, exactly how do we solve that?

As I couldn't solve the problem permanently, I asked over here and my expectation is that this problem will be solved.

Comment: [You might not need jQuery](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/) and [You might not need jQuery - Delegate](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#delegate). The native method is [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Nick's answer solved my problem after I tried that, but at least thank you guys...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's safer to also check for the current `readyState` in case the all the load events have already fired.

If you have multiple buttons/contents you should use `querySelectorAll`, if you only want to get the first/single you can use `querySelector`.

Have a look at the following example with a bit html and css:

```js
if (document.readyState === "complete") onLoad();
else addEventListener("load", onLoad);

function onLoad() {
  const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".js-all-btn");
  for (const button of buttons) button.addEventListener("click", onToggleButtonClick);
}

/**
 * @this {HTMLButtonElement} the target button
 */
function onToggleButtonClick() {
  this.classList.toggle("active");

  const contents = document.querySelectorAll(".js-all-content");
  for (const content of contents) content.classList.toggle("a-block");
}
```

```css
.active {
  background: red;
}

.a-block {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<button class="js-all-btn"> Button 1 </button>
<button class="js-all-btn"> Button 2 </button>

<div class="js-all-content"> Content 1 </div>
<div class="js-all-content"> Content 2 </div>
```

Mostly ES5 (IE11 Compatible)

```js
if (document.readyState === "complete") onLoad();
else addEventListener("load", onLoad);

function onLoad() {
  var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".js-all-btn");
  for (var index = 0; index < buttons.length; index++) {
    var button = buttons[index];
    button.addEventListener("click", onToggleButtonClick);
  }
}

/**
 * @this {HTMLButtonElement} the target button
 */
function onToggleButtonClick() {
  this.classList.toggle("active");

  var contents = document.querySelectorAll(".js-all-content");
  for (var index = 0; index < contents.length; index++) {
    var content = contents[index];
    content.classList.toggle("a-block");
  }
}
```

```css
.active {
  background: red;
}

.a-block {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<button class="js-all-btn"> Button 1 </button>
<button class="js-all-btn"> Button 2 </button>

<div class="js-all-content"> Content 1 </div>
<div class="js-all-content"> Content 2 </div>
```

If you need to support an older version of IE you might have to add a [polyfill](https://github.com/eligrey/classList.js/tree/master) for `classList.toggle`

Comment: Nick sorry, I almost forgot, is it compatible with all browsers?

Comment: @Nick do you have an example where DOMContentLoaded will not work and your readystate will? I have used DOMContentLoaded since I was told that "load" was not safe.

Comment: Also your code will fail if the button has children like icons which are clicked since the target will not be the button. Mine handles that

Comment: @mplungjan can you explain how "load" not safe? I'm using Nick's pure JS code right now but according to you, is it a risk? Thanks.

Comment: @mplungjan If the load event has already been fired (usually happens when the script is requested asynchronously) the event listener wouldn't trigger, hence the `readyState` check. I find it to be a safe auto-include in all load listeners since it just helps out in those rare cases and doesn't affect the code otherwise.

Comment: @mplungjan Good call about the `this` I added a `bind` call.

Comment: @Eagle It will not work for IE (due to the for of loops)

Comment: But now the bind is not needed since you have function: `function onToggleButtonClick() { this.classList.toggle("active"); }` and `button.addEventListener("click", onToggleButtonClick)` will do OK

Comment: In theory it would be fine, but I find it safer/more readable to add a separate variable. And bind seems cleaner than `() => onToggleButtonClick(button)` (but it's just personal preference at this point)

Comment: @nick zoum For all versions, or only for certain versions like 7 and 8?

Comment: @nickzoum but you do not have `() => onToggleButtonClick(button)`, you have `button.addEventListener("click", onToggleButtonClick)`  combined with `function onToggleButtonClick() { this.classList.toggle("active"); }`which does not get much cleaner. I do not like bind in any case  - especially not here. For arrow functions I will use event: 
`const onToggleButtonClick = (e) => { const tgt = e.target.closest("button"); if (!tgt) return; tgt.classList.toggle("active"); };`
`button.addEventListener("click", onToggleButtonClick)`

Comment: @Eagle Updated the answer to include an IE compatible version.

Comment: @mplungjan I updated the answer. However I think that since the function is on the global scope it is safer (and easier to call) if the target were to be passed as a parameter rather than a `this` reference. Furthermore a function parameter's name is bound to be more descriptive than `this` (hence why I previously said it would be more readable).

Comment: As it is seen, there are very smart people here at Stack Overflow. So, thank you both Nick Zoum and MPlungjan for providing such good and quality information. And also good to read such useful information. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is delegating. It is not clear how to solve this without knowing if you have one or more buttons with that class

If only ONE button, do this

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.querySelector("button.js-all-btn").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.target.toggleClass("active");
    document.querySelector(".js-all-content").toggleClass("a-block");
  });
});
```

If more than one button you can delegate

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.querySelector("someSelectorWrappingTheButtons").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    const tgt = e.target.closest("button.js-all-btn");
    if (!tgt) return; // not the button
    tgt.toggleClass("active");
    document.querySelector(".js-all-content").toggleClass("a-block"); // if this is a sibling of the js-all-btn then you need to navigate instead.
  });
});
```

Comment: I had no clue [closest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) was now in vanilla JS. Thanks for teaching me something new.